# Scala: Force child class to override all parent methods

Tags: scala

Is there any way to force the child classes to override all methods in the parent class in Scala? In Python there is @abstractmethod decorator to do the same, this would throw an exception if child class does not override the method. In looking for if such feature is available in scala..

Comment: just make the parent class `abstract` and do not provide any implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Make your parent class `abstract`, and don't implement any methods that you want the derived classes to be forced to implement.

```
abstract class Foo {
  def foo(s: String): Int
}
```

Here's what would happen (at compile time) if a child class failed to implement `foo`

```
scala> class Bar extends Foo
<console>:12: error: class Bar needs to be abstract, since method foo in 
class Foo of type (s: String)Int is not defined
   class Bar extends Foo
         ^
```